# How to extend functionality of a library class?

Tags: c++, oop, unicode, mfc, polymorphism

**Problem**

I build my project in Unicode but I need the CMyDoc::Serialize() function to read/write file (think strings) in ASCII. The problem is that once in Unicode, CArchive class automatically read/write all the strings in Unicode as well which I don't want.

**My Solution**

My solution is derive my own class `CArchiveA` from `CArchive` which supports ASCII strings as well. Here is my class definition.

```
class CArchiveA : public CArchive
{

public:
    CArchiveA(CFile* pFile,
                UINT nMode,
                int nBufSize = 4096,
                void* lpBuf = NULL);

    CArchiveA( CArchive & ar );

    virtual ~CArchiveA();

    BOOL ReadStringA(CStringA& rString);
    LPSTR ReadStringA(_Out_z_cap_(nMax+1) LPSTR lpsz, _In_ UINT nMax);

    void WriteStringA(LPCSTR lpsz);


};
```

Now I was hoping to do something like this in the doc's file `Serialize` function.

```
void CTestDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    CArchiveA & ar_a ( ar );

    // text is of type CStringA

    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        // TODO: add storing code here
        ar_a.WriteStringA( text );
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: add loading code here

        ar_a.ReadStringA( text );
    }
}
```

But the first line above `CArchiveA & ar_a ( ar );` is compiler error.

**Question**

Maybe I am feeling just rusty today but how can I convert `CArchive` to my own derived class `CArchiveA` so I can work with it? Is it any better if I don't derive from `CArchive` and instead write helper functions which would accept `CArchive` as first parameter and write the ASCII strings?

I find this an interesting case study of extending functionality of a base class from a given library. I would love to explore that aspect in the solution as well while looking for Object Oriented Design. I have my share of thoughts, but would like to listen to you first. The question in that sense would be what is the best way to solve a problem like this when (say) a library class is falling a bit short of functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think containment is a better tool than inheritance for this job.

By public inheritance, you are saying that `CArchiveA` is-a `CArchive`.

This relationship is not commutative.  It is akin to a parent-child relationship.  Thus, a `CArchive` object *is not* a `CArchiveA` object, and you can't use a `CArchiveA` reference to point to a `CArchive` object.

A better choice would be to make your `CArchiveA` class a wrapper around the `CArchive` object, and contain it rather than inherit from it.  You can define a constructor for `CArchiveA` that takes in a `CArchive` object or reference, and keeps a reference to it, and then defines your `ReadString/WriteString` methods to do what you want.

If `CArchive` implements some abstract interface, you may want to derive `CArchiveA` from that as well.  But if not, you probably don't want to use inheritance for this.

Comment: That's a good way to put it. When I tried ` CTestDoc::Serialize(CArchiveA& ar)' the function wouldn't be called by the framework anymore so this speaks for what said `CArchive` is not `CArchiveA`